# Calculation from specific array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following array written in PHP.
I need a way to print values by name, and if possible, do calculations with specific values (by looping through).

```
[MAIN] => Array
    (
        [FIRST] => Array
            (
                [0] => 500
                [1] => 1000
                [2] => 1500
            )

        [SECOND] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Nick
                [State] => None

            )

    )
```

For example, by using the array above i'd like to print only the NAME of the "SECOND" array but without looping through every index (without using an index at all), and add each value of the "FIRST" array by looping throu them.

Thank you!

Comment: echo $array['MAIN']['SECOND']['Name'];

Comment: Thank you sir! That did the job! And if i may ask, how can i do math with the values of "FIRST" array? Thanks again!!!

Comment: ill answer in the answer box

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = 0;
foreach ($array['MAIN']['FIRST'] as $val) {
    $result += $val;
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first question is like this:

`echo $array['MAIN']['SECOND']['Name'];`

You have an array of an array of an array so you have to dereference values as such.

The second one would look something like this:

```
$var = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $var += $array['MAIN']['FIRST'][$i];
}
echo $var;
```

Comment: You type arguments for `for` cycle, and it's do not work with `foreach`

Comment: oops my bad, started with foreach and changed my mind :P